# How can I use Postfix as a spam filter frontend for a Google Apps domain?

Tags: email, postfix, g-suite

I have a domain that has its email hosted by Google Apps.  This domain is similar (it's the .com while the real ISP is a .net) to an old major ISP and the count in "Spam" folder for the catch-all account is constantly almost a million emails per 30 days.  Not only does the domain receive misaddressed emails, it receives all of the misaddressed Spam too.  It receives so much Spam that Google sometimes get overwhelmed (or they decided to punish us) and will sometimes bounce legitimate emails as well as Spam.

So, what I'd like to do is have a Ubuntu VPN running Postfix filter out as much spam as possible. A small number of addresses and variations receive a huge proportion of the bad email, so it will be easy to filter a lot of this out.

Here is what I'd like to do:

1. Emails that get sent to whatever@example.com go to my VPS at email.example.com
2. Postfix on email.example.com deletes a huge percentage of the Spam
3. email.example.com takes the email that is left, and sends it over to Google.
4. Google routes the email to the correct email box.

Is this possible?  And, if so, can anyone give me a walkthough on how I can implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure that is possible.  I don't know the exact details you would need for Postfix, but Google describes this basic setup on this [page](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=60730).

Comment: I actually spent a lot of time searching for this earlier.  I guess I needed to specify "inbound" in my queries.